# Hide text using aura:if

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute, aura-if

I'm trying to troubleshoot here for a day.

My end goal here is to hide the **Test** text, depending on the **Product_Family__c** value.

Here is the code, please let me know what am I missing.

**Apex**

```
public class updateCheckBoxPlan {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateChk(String key){
        Opportunity acc = [SELECT Id, Name, Submit_Go_No_Go_Question__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:key];
        if(acc.Submit_Go_No_Go_Question__c == false){
            acc.Submit_Go_No_Go_Question__c = true;
        }
        /* else{
             acc.Submit_Go_No_Go_Question__c = false;
        } */
        UPDATE acc;
    }

        @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean getOppty(String key){
        Opportunity acc = [SELECT Id, Product_Family__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:key];  
        if(acc.Product_Family__c!=''){
        return false;
        }else{
        return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**CMP**

```
<aura:component controller="updateCheckBoxPlan"
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="opp" type="Boolean" />
         <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.isRefreshed}" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.opp}">
        <div aura:id="myDiv" class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="color:red">
            <p><b>Test</b></p>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:8rem">        
        <lightning:button label="Confirm Submission"
                          variant="brand"
                          onclick="{!c.updateCheck }"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({

     doInit : function(component, event) {
         var action = component.get("c.getOppty");
                 action.setParams({ key :component.get("v.recordId") });

         action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
             component.set("v.opp", a.getReturnValue());
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(action);
     },

    updateCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
        var rid = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.updateChk");
        action.setParams({key : rid});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();


            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.opp",true );
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();  
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    console.log("Unknown Error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    isRefreshed: function(component, event, helper) {
        location.reload();
    },
})
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: irstly, are you getting recordId? Secondly, Test should be shown if Product_Family__c is empty?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get the recordId. Yes, Test should be equal to blank. I tried to test it by opening two records one has a value and one does not have, the output is just the same.

Comment: try putting alert(component.get("v.recordId")) in `doInit` as first line and can you confirm if you are getting recordId ?

Comment: I'm getting the correct recordID

Comment: I think the issue is withing v.opp, but I'm still trying to know what is the problem. The value is always equals to _false_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have implemented is fine and should work. However, here are the checkpoints you can do:

1. You should load this component in `Opportunity Record page`.
2. You should implement error handling in callback to know what could be the problem:

   ```
   action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       var state = response.getState();
       if (state === "SUCCESS") {
           component.set("v.opp", a.getReturnValue());
       }
       else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
           console.log("Incomplete");
       }
       else if (state === "ERROR") {
           var errors = response.getError();
           if (errors) {
               if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                   console.log("Error message: " + 
                            errors[0].message);
               }
           } else {
               console.log("Unknown error");
           }
       }
   });
   ```

and check the browser (chrome) console for error logs

**Note:**

Instead of using `!=''` or `!=null`, you should be using standard string functions like `isBlank` or `isNotBlank`:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean getOppty(String key){
    Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Product_Family__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:key];  
    return String.isBlank(opp.Product_Family__c);
}
```

Also, use better naming convention like `opp` instead of `acc` so that you dont have confusion.

Comment: `return String.isBlank(opp.Product_Family__c);` solved it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: WC ). Implement proper error handling using toast messaging in callback - recommended than console logs